# I have not received the token in the subsequent request of that request in which I have send the cookie to the front-end

Tags: node.js, cookies, jwt, mern

before this when I login in this website it is sending the token in cookie this token is received in network tab of browser and it is also checked by insomnia it send the token and it save in the cookie section of insomnia but when I try the subsequent get request that is in this following code it is reached at the backed but it print on the terminal "back-end" and then "we don't have token " but on the insomnia all the subsequent request are fine they verify the token after login

**main.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

**app.jsx**

```
import { Suspense, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

import Website from "./pages/Website";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Layout from "./components/Layout/Layout";
import Properties from "./pages/Properties/Properties";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "react-query";
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from "react-query/devtools";
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import Property from "./pages/Property/Property";
import  { UserDetailContextProvider } from "./context/UserDetailContext";
import Login from "./pages/Login/Login";
import Register from "./pages/Register/Register";

function App() {
  const queryClient = new QueryClient();

  
  return (
    <UserDetailContextProvider>
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Suspense fallback={<div>loading...</div>}>
            <Routes>
              <Route element={<Layout />}>
                <Route path="/" element={<Website />} />
                <Route path="/properties">
                  <Route index element={<Properties />} />
                  <Route path=":propertyId" element={<Property />} />
                </Route>
                
                <Route path="/login" element={<Login/>} />
                <Route path="/register" element={<Register/>} />
              </Route>
            </Routes>
          </Suspense>
        </BrowserRouter>
        <ToastContainer />
        <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
      </QueryClientProvider>
    </UserDetailContextProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**this is  login page  **

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { loginUser } from "../../utils/api";
import { UserDetailContext } from "../../context/UserDetailContext";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";



const Login = () => {
  const { userDetails, setUserDetails } = useContext(UserDetailContext);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [credential, setCredential] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const handleClick = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    const userInfo = {
      email: credential.email,
      password: credential.password,
    };

    const user = await loginUser(userInfo);
    
    setUserDetails(user);
    
    localStorage.setItem("user",JSON.stringify(user));
    navigate("/");
  };

  return (
    <div className="wrapper flexColCenter">
      <form
        className="wrapper flexColCenter paddings"
        style={{ gap: "1rem" }}
        onSubmit={handleClick}
      >
        <label>Email</label>
        <input
          type="email"
          placeholder="email"
          value={credential.email}
          onChange={(e) =>
            setCredential({ ...credential, email: e.target.value })
          }
        />
        <label>Password</label>
        <input
          type="password"
          placeholder="password"
          value={credential.password}
          onChange={(e) =>
            setCredential({ ...credential, password: e.target.value })
          }
        />
        <button type="submit" className="button">
          login
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

**this is api for login**

```
import axios from "axios";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";


export const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8000/api",
});


export const loginUser = async (userInfo) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const res = await api.post("/user/login", userInfo);
      console.log("loging user : ",res.data);
      if (res.data.error) {
        toast.error(res.data.error);
        reject(res.data.error);
      } else {
        toast.success(res.data.message);
        resolve(res.data);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error("something went wrong");
      reject(error);
    }
  });
};
```

**this is the next subsequent get request after the login**

```
export const profile = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await api.get("/user/profile");
    console.log("done")
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
}
```

**this is index.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import cors from 'cors';
import { userRoute } from './routes/userRoute.js';
import { resindencyRoute } from './routes/resindencyRoute.js';
dotenv.config()

const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.json())
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(cors({
     credentials: true,
    origin: "http://localhost:5173",
}))
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));

app.listen(PORT, ()=> {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});

app.use('/api/user', userRoute);

app.use('/api/residency', resindencyRoute);
```

**this is userRoute.js**

```
import express from "express";
import { 
    createUser, 
    bookVisit,
    getAllBookings,
    cancelBooking,
    updateFavList, 
    favList
} from "../controllers/userController.js";
import jwtCheck from "../config/authConfig.js";
import  {registerUser}  from "../controllers/registerUser.js";
import { loginUser } from "../controllers/loginUser.js";
import { getProfile } from "../controllers/getProfile.js";

const router = express.Router();

// router.post("/register", createUser);
router.post("/register", registerUser)
router.post("/login", loginUser)
router.get("/profile", getProfile)
router.post("/bookVisit/:id", bookVisit);
router.get("/allBookings", getAllBookings);
// router.get("/allMyResidencies", getAllMyResidencies);
router.post("/removeBooking/:id", cancelBooking);
router.post("/updateFavList/:rid", updateFavList);
router.get("/favList", favList);

export { router as userRoute };
```

**this is where I have send token means its loginUser.js**

```
import asyncHandler from "express-async-handler";
import { prisma } from "../config/prismaConfig.js";
import { comparePassword } from "../helper/helper.js";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

export const loginUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  try {
    const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({ where: { email } });
    console.log(user);
    if (user) {
      const match = await comparePassword(password, user.password);
      if (match) {
        const userInfo = {
          name: user.name,
          email: user.email,
          id: user.id,
          image: user.image,
          bookedVisits: user.bookedVisits,
          favResidenciesID: user.favResidenciesID,
        };
        jwt.sign(userInfo,process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY,{},(err,token) =>{
             if(err)
               throw err;
            console.log("token : ",token)
            console.log("user inf ; " , userInfo);
            res.cookie("token",token,{ expires: new Date((new Date()).getTime() + (10 * 86400000)),httpOnly: true }).json(userInfo);
        });
        // res.send({
        //   message: `Welcome ${user.name}`,
        //   user: user,
        // });
      } else {
        res.send({
          error: "Wrong password",
        });
      }
    } else {
      res.send({
        error: "Email does not exists",
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.send({
      error: "Something Went Wrong",
    });
    throw error;
  }
});
```

**this is getProfile.js code**

```
import asyncHandler from "express-async-handler";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

export const getProfile = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  console.log("back-end")
  try {
       const {token} = req.cookies;
       if(token){
          console.log("yes token : ",token)
          jwt.verify(token,process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY,{},(err,userInfo)=>{
            if(err)
               throw err;
            res.json(userInfo);
          })
       }
       else{
        console.log("we don't have token");
        res.send({
            message:"unothorized user"
        })
       }
    }
   catch (error) {
      throw error;
  }
});
```

when I login the token I visible in header of the login request in the network tab of browser and It does not saved in the cookie tab
I have try many time but it not working I need the solution of this project please help me out

Comment: So, this isnt fully reproduce-able.  For your backend we all need to see how you setup the app, are you setting it up with cookie-parser(or some other tool for cookie mangement) correctly on the backend?  And for the frontend is the cookie/response being integrated and passed along correctly(include code for the initial all)?  We need more backend and frontend code to verify it

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.